# Displaying has and belongs to many associations in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hey I'm new to  Rails and all this so bear with me, thanks!

I have two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
end

class Sport < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

My users have a few different sports that they can choose each. I'm simply trying to display all users in a table, along with which sports they do. However.. the only way I've managed to get anything without an error is by using current_user as shown below. I've been looking how to do this for hours... I know it's going to be stupidly simple but I just can't figure it out or even know how to go in the right direction.

```
# users_controller.rb
def index
 @users = User.all
 @sports = current_user.sports
end

# users/index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
   <td><%= link_to user.email, user %></td>
    <% @sports.each do |s| %>
     <td><%= s.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

That's my current code but obviously this shows only the signed in users associations and repeats it for the other users like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Sport 1:</th>
<th>2:</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>User 1 (current_user)</td>
<td>Football</td>
<td>Running</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>User 2</td>
<td>Football (User 1's Sports)</td>
<td>Running </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using user.sports while looping through each of the user will lead to N+1 queries on your database. You can change your controller method to something like

```
def index
 @users = User.all.eager_load(:sports)
end
```

and then in html

```
<% user.sports.each do |s| %>
 <td><%= s.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

This will load users along with left_outer_join on sports table and this will save to lot of extra queries on your database.

For Info you can refer this [good blog](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following and deleting `@sports = current_user.sports`:

```
<% user.sports.each do |s| %>
 <td><%= s.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! As expected it was extremely simple